# How to set up Mockito to mock class for Android unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

If I make a simple test case like

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    Spanned word = new SpannedString("Bird");
    int length = word.length();
}
```

an exception is thrown

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Method length in
>   android.text.SpannableStringInternal not mocked. See
>   http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

This is explained in the link above as

> The android.jar file that is used to run unit tests does not contain
>   any actual code - that is provided by the Android system image on real
>   devices. Instead, all methods throw exceptions (by default). This is
>   to make sure your unit tests only test your code and do not depend on
>   any particular behaviour of the Android platform (that you have not
>   explicitly mocked e.g. using Mockito).

So how do you set up Mockito in an Android project in order to mock classes like this?

*I want to learn, so I am going to add my answer below Q&A style.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not difficult to set up Mockito in your project. The steps are below.

## 1. Add the Mockito dependency

Assuming you are using  the jcenter repository (the default in Android Studio), add the following line to the `dependencies` block of your app's *build.gradle* file:

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47"
```

You can update the version number to whatever is the [most recent Mockito version](https://bintray.com/mockito/maven/mockito) is.

It should look something like this:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47"
}
```

## 2. Import Mockito into your test class

By importing a static class you can make the code more readable (ie, instead of calling `Mockito.mock()`, you can just use `mock()`).

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

## 3. Mock objects in your tests

You need to do three things to mock objects.

1. Create a mock of the class using `mock(TheClassName.class)`.
2. Tell the mocked class what to return for any methods you need to call. You do this using `when` and `thenReturn`.
3. Use the mocked methods in your tests.

Here is an example. A real test would probably use the mocked value as some sort of input for whatever is being tested.

```
public class MyTestClass {

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {
        // 1. create mock
        Spanned word = mock(SpannedString.class);

        // 2. tell the mock how to behave
        when(word.length()).thenReturn(4);

        // 3. use the mock
        assertEquals(4, word.length());
    }
}
```

## Further study

There is a lot more to Mockito. See the following resources to continue your learning.

- [Mockito documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html)
- [Unit tests with Mockito - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html)
- [Mockito on Android](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/mockito-on-android-88f84656910)
- [Testing made sweet with a Mockito by Jeroen Mols](http://Testing%20made%20sweet%20with%20a%20Mockito%20by%20Jeroen%20Mols) (YouTube)

## Or try this...

It is good to learn mocking because it is fast and isolates the code being tested. However, if you are testing some code that uses an Android API, it might be easier to just use an instrumentation test rather than a unit test. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273251/3681880).

Comment: The question was about instrumentation tests, not unit tests.